# Create horizontal accordion as in the attached image

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-accordion

Can anybody please help me creating the same horizontal accordian menu with all the tabs default right side with small arrow images on those tabs.

The main idea is to change the arrow directions as and when moving right to left.

I googled jquery accordians but found without arrows.

Thanks in advance
Ramesh.T.

[image]

Comment: I've just seen your edit. If your looking for an accordion that does EXACTLY what that screen shot does you'll probably be out of luck. Adding in directional arrows is a very trivial thing to modify an existing accordion into supporting. If your looking for someone to write it for you, sorry to disappoint but this probably isn't the place to be looking.

Comment: For some rough direction on how to implement this: Use the OnClick event to point the arrow in the direction needed depending on the slide direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some good examples of how to do exactly that:

http://www.portalzine.de/index?/Horizontal_Accordion

http://letmehaveblog.blogspot.com/2007/10/haccordion-simple-horizontal-accordion.html

http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-examples-horizontal-accordion/

The second link has an extremely basic implementation, good to use as a reference if your not experienced.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[This is a cool example for that.](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slide-out-and-drawer-effect/) The only thing you need to re-arrange them.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html could be a good start or http://www.gethifi.com/blog/tutorial-a-horizontal-jquery-accordion-using-custom-event-binding looks almost exactly like what you want.